# How do i access redis deployed in a separate service and my rails app in a separate service AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-service-connect, ecs-service-connect

I have set up two services in AWS ECS: one for my Rails application and another for Redis. Both services are running as separate tasks on AWS Fargate. Additionally, I am using ECS Service Connect to enable service discovery and communication between services. However, I'm facing challenges in configuring the network and accessing Redis from my Rails app, as it keeps reporting 'Invalid URL' when trying to connect to Redis.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I want to connect my Rails application to the Redis service to utilize it for caching and other functionalities using ECS Service Connect.

1. How do I properly configure the network, security groups, and ECS Service Connect to allow communication between the Rails app and Redis service?
2. What changes do I need to make to my Rails application's configuration to connect to the Redis service using ECS Service Connect?
3. Are there any specific URL formats or endpoints that ECS Service Connect provides for accessing services within the same VPC?

I have followed the AWS documentation on setting up ECS Service Connect, but my Rails app still reports 'Invalid URL' when trying to connect to Redis. I suspect I might be missing something in the configuration or using the wrong URL format.

Any guidance on the steps required to establish communication between these two services using ECS Service Connect and resolving the 'Invalid URL' issue would be greatly appreciated. If there are any best practices or recommended approaches for setting up this type of architecture on AWS ECS with ECS Service Connect, please share them as well